# Conditional: More than 1

Tags: grammatical-number, word-usage, verb-agreement

> The stoplight turns green if there (is/are) more than 1 car(s) waiting

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out the above statement. Which configuration is correct?

This is odd, as I'm a native English speaker in my mid-twenties, and I like to think my vocabulary and understanding of the English language is pretty good...but I'm always willing to learn!

Comment: Ah, yes, you are correct. I tried to search first, but wasn't really sure how to phrase the question, and that one didn't come up. Thanks for the heads up. Mods, feel free to close it as a duplicate.

Comment: As a side note, let me remind you that you have the alternative of saying "The stoplight turns green if more than one car is waiting." And the popular preference is so strong here that few people are tempted to say "if more than one car are waiting."